# How to delete edge and vertices from directed graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

Given **u** and **v** I want to delete the **u** vertex and **u,v** edge from an adjacency list graph. The approach I followed is to delete the vertex from root and from the other sets of other roots.

exemple :

I want to delete the vertex u

```
u -> a b c d
x -> u   // u should be deleted
```

here s a brief description of my class :

```
template <class T>
class Digraph
{
public:
    Digraph();
    ~Digraph();

void delete_vertex(T u);
void delete_edge(T u, T v);


private:
    std::map<T, std::set<T>> graph;
}
```

What I tried :

```
template <class T>
void Digraph<T>::delete_vertex(T u)
{
    graphe.erase(u);

    for (auto const &pair : graphe)
    {
        for (auto const &elem : pair.second)
        {
            if(elem == u){
                pair->second.erase(u);
            }
        }
    }
}

template <class T>
void Digraph<T>::delete_edge(T u, T v)
{
    std::set<T> s = graphe[u];
    s.erase(v);
}
```

I wonder if what I'm doing in the delete_vertex function is right, because it doesn't work, maybe I forgot something, can someone help me with that?

Comment: What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: `pair.second` or `pair->second`? Only one of those will work.

Comment: Also, removing elements from a container you're iterating usually won't end well. Check what [`std::set<T>::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) *returns*.

Comment: And please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). If you ask about build errors (which you should get with your current [mre]) then copy-paste (as text!) the full and complete build-log into the question, and add comments on the lines where you get the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both functions are bugged. The problem with `delete_edge` is that you are **copying** the set of edges, and you then erase from the copy not the original. This is the common beginner mistake of treating C++ objects as if they are references when they aren't. Here's version that really uses a reference

```
template <class T>
void Digraph<T>::delete_edge(T u, T v)
{
    std::set<T>& s = graphe[u]; // s is a reference
    s.erase(v);
}
```

but just eliminating the variable is even simpler (IMHO)

```
template <class T>
void Digraph<T>::delete_edge(T u, T v)
{
    graphe[u].erase(v);
}
```

The problem with `delete_vertex` is as Some Programmer Dude says, you cannot erase from a container if you are iterating through it. Here's an iterator based solution

```
template <class T>
void Digraph<T>::delete_vertex(T u)
{
    graphe.erase(u);
    for (auto const &pair : graphe)
    {
        auto i = pair.second.begin();
        while (i != pair.second.end())
        {
            if (*i == u)
                i = pair.second.erase(i);
            else
                ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

It's even illegal to use `++` on an iterator to an erased element, which is why `erase` returns an iterator to the next element.

Untested code, so apologies for any mistakes.